# Change colour of excel cell using pandas

Tags: python, excel, pandas, dataframe, background-color

I am using panda lib to get dataframe of the excel file. I want to change the background color and save it as the excel file. How Can I do it?

I tried using stylers but it asked me to import Jinja2. I use eclipse IDE and company computer. How to solve it.thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As it is explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39299509/coloring-cells-in-excel-with-pandas): You can create a function to do the highlighting:

```
def highlight_cells():
    # provide your criteria for highlighting the cells here
    return ['background-color: yellow']
```

And then apply your highlighting function to your dataframe:

```
df.style.apply(highlight_cells)
```

Comment: Does this change the color when written back to an Excel file?